# When the bell rang, we had NOT finished our work

Tags: past-tense

> When the bell rang, we had NOT finished our work.

Does it mean: **We were still working at the time the bell rang.**

I think that "finish working" and "finish work" are not the same.

I think that it CAN mean that we were still working but it can also mean that we intended to finished the work later.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a school context.

Schoolchildren have work, and they do work, but they are not *at work*.

So it merely means that these children had not finished the task that had been assigned to them.

I would infer that they were working when the bell rang. This is because children normally have to do work in lessons until they finish, or until the bell rings. This is an inference, based on my general understanding of schools, rather than stated.

Consider:

> > John's history teacher told the class to write an essay about the Romans.
>
> What did John do in the history class?

You would suppose that he wrote an essay about the Romans. It doesn't mean "John wrote an essay." It doesn't state anything about what John did.

Similarly, the children in your example could have spent the whole lesson making paper airplanes!

Even if it is an adult context, it still means the same "We had not finished the assigned task."

Comment: James, one of my American acquaintances insists that the ORIGINAL sentence implies that ""We were still working at the time the bell rang". But I am not sure that it is 100% accurate. Maybe, we were working, maybe we weren't. Is his inference correct or is it just an option?

Comment: @user1425 The words used do not make it clear as to whether they were still working or not, merely that their work was unfinished.

Comment: I would infer that as the task hadn't been finished (and assuming diligent students) that they were still working...  It is an inference, not an implication.  Children in school don't normally get the option to not work in a lesson.

Comment: But on the other hand, if the lesson is over they are unlikely to continue working. So, as you both say it's only a possibility not a fact.

Comment: It says nothing about the speaker's intentions, and the exact meaning depends on context.